# C# - Unzip all files in directory and its subdirectories

Tags: c#, unzip, 7zip

I try to extract all ZIP archives in their respective directory / subdirectory to their respective directory / subdirectory.

Example of the structure:

```
-Root-Directory
  - File.txt
  - Fi.docx
  - Files.zip
      - TestEx.jpg
      - Example.png
  - /Subdirectory_1
      - ExampleData.txt
      - Example.xlsx
      - Archive1.zip
           - ExampleData_1.txt
           - ExampleData_2.txt
      - Archiv2.zip
           - Data1.txt
           - Data2.txt
      - ...
  - /Subdirectory_2
      - T_1.txt
      - ABC.xlsx
      - ZippedFiles.zip
           - Imag_1.jpeg
           - Imag_2.gif
      - ZipFiles.zip
           - Music.wav
           - Sound.mp3
```

How it should look like:

```
-Root-Directory
  - File.txt
  - Fi.docx
  - TestEx.jpg
  - Example.png
  - /Subdirectory_1
      - ExampleData.txt
      - Example.xlsx
      - ExampleData_1.txt
      - ExampleData_2.txt
      - Data1.txt
      - Data2.txt
      - ...
  - /Subdirectory_2
      - T_1.txt
      - ABC.xlsx
      - Imag_1.jpeg
      - Imag_2.gif
      - Music.wav
      - Sound.mp3
```

My attempt:

```
private static void unzipAllFiles(DirectoryInfo directoryPath)
        {
            foreach( DirectoryInfo dirs in directoryPath.GetDirectories() )
            {
                foreach (FileInfo file in dirs.GetFiles())
                {   
                    if(Path.GetExtension(file.FullName).Equals(".zip"))
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
                        string zPath = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe";// change the path and give yours 
                        try
                        {
                            ProcessStartInfo pro = new ProcessStartInfo();
                            pro.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                            pro.FileName = zPath;
                            pro.Arguments = "x -r -aou \"" + file.FullName;
                            Process process = Process.Start(pro);
                            process.WaitForExit();
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception Ex)
                        {
                            //DO logic here 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

A few things here:

1. How to surpress the opening of the `cmd.exe`?
2. It does not even iterate through the ZIP archives in the root directory. How to fix this?
3. Although the output of 7zip on `cmd.exe` prints that some extracting is processed, nothing happens. How to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Why are you not using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=netcore-3.1 ?

Comment: Maybe skip `7z` and use `ZipArchive` and `ZipFile` from .NET standard library? Here is a good example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.openread?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried it with that but was not successful either. :(

Comment: Please show us that attempt.

Comment: I see nothing specifying where the files are supposed to be written.  I think it's writing them to the current directory, not the directory where the .zip files are.

Comment: Why was my comment deleted?

Answer (score -2):

Try writing a method that extracts a zip then iterates over its extracted contents to look for and extract any other zip files. You can use the ZipFile, FileInfo, and DirectoryInfo classes. Here's some psuedo code...

```
func extractZip
    // extract zip file
    // call extractZipsFromDir using base extract path

func extractZipsFromDir
    // get list of all .zip files in cur dir
    // while list.len > 0
        // for each zip file
            // extract to curr dir
            // delete the zip
        // set list of zips to new list of all .zip files in cur dir which will pick up any newly extracted zips
    // get list of all directories in cur dir (don't include sub directories)
    // for each dir in list
        // call extractZipsFromDir with iterated dir
```